# C++ Windows Application Form Cannot make Forward Declaration

Tags: c++, forms, class, declare

I am using Visual `C++ 2010`, in Windows Application Form:

```
#pragma once

namespace MyProgram {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

ref class Design;       //Forward Declariong of Class Design

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
private:
    Design Enviroment;  //Declaring object of class: Design
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }
    };


public ref class Design
    {
    private:
        String^ Color;
    public:
        Design()
                {
                     //TODO: Add the Constructor code here
                }
    };
```

And i get the `error: MyProgram::Form1::Enviroment'` uses undefined class '`MyProgram::Design`'

If I switch the definition order, it will compile with no errors, but in windows application form the class Form1 always has to be first... So, is my forward declaration wrong?

Comment: Now it says  use of undefined type 'MyProgram::Design'

Comment: I don't think that the operator ^ is the problem, because if i switch the definition order, it will compile with no errors... Something else is wrong here

Comment: because Design is an inner class of your form... so the forward declaration doesn't match the form1::Design type!

Comment: No, it is not, actually I did a bad copy paste... It is not Inner, check it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are declaring a variable (Environment) of type Design the complete type has to be available to the compiler at that time.

By re-ordering your declarations, you are providing the complete type to the compiler.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: Declare the type before it is used.  That is the solution.  Either in a separate header file to be included or above in the same file.

Comment: Well, this would be a nice solution. However, i told you this is impossible, because if i declare my class before the class Form1, visual studio hides the form, in order to "To prevent loss of data". So the only way to do it is actually create a header file?